# Chrome produces no audio after reaching 50 audio output streams

Tags: google-chrome, audio, webrtc

During my testing, I have found out that reaching 50 audio output streams (as displayed in chrome://media-internals/ Audio tab) on a single tab causes the audio output to disappear. Does Chrome have a set maximum limit of audio output streams allowed per displayed tab? If so, is there some workaround for that? The Chrome version that I am using is Version 87.0.4280.141.

Whenever we're muting/unmuting the audio(second function below) and adjusting the mic volume(first function below), we create a new audio context. Does too many audio context instances caused the issue?

```js
private setLocalStreamVolume(stream: MediaStream | undefined) {
    const context = new AudioContext()
    const destination = context.createMediaStreamDestination()
    const gainNode = context.createGain()
    if (stream) {
        for(const track of stream.getTracks()){
            const sourceStream = context.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([track]));    
            sourceStream.connect(gainNode)
            gainNode.connect(destination)
            gainNode.gain.value = this._micVolume            
        }        
    }
    return destination.stream
  }


export function mixStreams(streams: Iterable<(MediaStream | undefined)>) {
    const context = new AudioContext()
    const mixedOutput = context.createMediaStreamDestination()
    for(const stream of streams)
        if(stream)
            for(const track of stream.getTracks()){
                const sourceStream = context.createMediaStreamSource(new MediaStream([track]));
                sourceStream.connect(mixedOutput);
            }
    return mixedOutput.stream.getTracks()[0]
}
```

Comment: Are you using 50 PeerConnections? If so, there are 50 opus encodings going on. Check your CPU.

Comment: There are only 2 peerConnections (based on dump from chrome://webrtc-internals) at the time the audio was gone.

The reason we are reaching 50 audio output streams is because every time we adjust the mic volume or mute the audio, we're creating a new audio context as follows:

Does creating too many audio contexts caused the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does too many audio context interactions caused the issue?

Too many AudioContext instances certainly will.  In fact, on some systems you can only use a single AudioContext.

I'm not sure what your specific use case is, but you probably only need one AudioContext.  All your MediaStreamSourceNodes can live in the same context.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: Using single audio context indeed resolved the issue! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoyceA No problem!  You can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks again Brad. So I just have a follow-up question. After switching to a single audio context, I am now getting poor audio quality for my microphone input after changing the gain node value. Any ideas why it is happening? Thanks!

Comment: @JoyceA Post a new question, along with a way to reproduce it.  I'm guessing that you're clipping.  You may need to use a compressor node and lower your levels.