# Web Audio API sound interaction stops working after a while

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm working with the Web Audio API for my javascript project, and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to find the answer for anywhere.

I've added event listeners to respond to keydown events- every time a user presses a certain key on their keyboard, a sound will play. This works for a little while, but after maybe around 6 seconds of pressing keys, something happens that makes the sound stop - the keys won't produce sound for maybe half a second, then they will start working again. Anyone have any idea why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Here's my code for the event listener :

```
import Audio from './scripts/audio'

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    const audio = new Audio();
    let key = e.key;
    audio.createNotes(key);

})
```

and here's my code for the audio :

```
class Audio {
    constructor() {
        // instantiate web audio api object 

        this.audioContext = new AudioContext();

        // create gain node, gain corresponds with volume

        this.gainNode = this.audioContext.createGain();
        this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.08, 0);

        // allows volume to decrease with time

        this.gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, this.audioContext.currentTime + 1.5);


    }

    createNotes(key) {

        // C4 to C5 scale, attach frequencies to corresponding keyboard value

        const notes = {
            's': 261.63,
            'd': 293.66,
            'f': 329.63,
            'g': 349.23,
            'h': 392.00,
            'j': 440.00,
            'k': 493.88,
            'l': 523.25,
            'e': 587.33,
            'r': 659.25,
            't': 698.46,
            'y': 783.99,
            'u': 880.00,
            'i': 987.77,
            'o': 1046.50,
            'p': 1174.66
        }
        
            // if e.key corresponds with notes key, we want to play sound
        
        if (notes[key]) {

            // oscillator corresponds with frequency, 
            // create oscillator node to attach frequency from notes object

            let oscillator = this.audioContext.createOscillator();
            oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(notes[key], this.audioContext.currentTime);

            // lower gain for higher frequency notes

            if (notes[key] > 699) {
                this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.03, this.audioContext.currentTime);
            }

            // connect oscillator node to volume node

            oscillator.connect(this.gainNode);

            // connect gain node to destination (speakers)

            this.gainNode.connect(this.audioContext.destination);

            oscillator.start(0);

            // tone will play for 1.5 seconds 

            oscillator.stop(this.audioContext.currentTime + 1.5)
        }
    }


}

export default Audio;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating too many AudioContext instances. This is not the intended usage of the API. Why are you creating so many instances? You should re-use them.

Generally you should only need a single AudioContext. On the mozzila developer page it's clearly stated that some Chrome versions only support 6.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/AudioContext#google_chrome

Here's a question/answer that further explains the problem.
[Chrome produces no audio after reaching 50 audio output streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689984/chrome-produces-no-audio-after-reaching-50-audio-output-streams)

To solve your problem basically create a single AudioContext and make it accessible globally like so:

```js
let globalAudioContext = new AudioContext();

class Audio
{
    constructor()
    {
        // instantiate web audio api object 


        // create gain node, gain corresponds with volume

        this.gainNode = globalAudioContext.createGain();
        this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.08, 0);

        // allows volume to decrease with time

        this.gainNode.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.001, globalAudioContext.currentTime + 1.5);


    }

    createNotes(key)
    {

        // C4 to C5 scale, attach frequencies to corresponding keyboard value

        const notes = {
            's': 261.63,
            'd': 293.66,
            'f': 329.63,
            'g': 349.23,
            'h': 392.00,
            'j': 440.00,
            'k': 493.88,
            'l': 523.25,
            'e': 587.33,
            'r': 659.25,
            't': 698.46,
            'y': 783.99,
            'u': 880.00,
            'i': 987.77,
            'o': 1046.50,
            'p': 1174.66
        }

        // if e.key corresponds with notes key, we want to play sound

        if (notes[key]) {

            // oscillator corresponds with frequency, 
            // create oscillator node to attach frequency from notes object

            let oscillator = globalAudioContext.createOscillator();
            oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(notes[key], globalAudioContext.currentTime);

            // lower gain for higher frequency notes

            if (notes[key] > 699) {
                this.gainNode.gain.setValueAtTime(0.03, globalAudioContext.currentTime);
            }

            // connect oscillator node to volume node

            oscillator.connect(this.gainNode);

            // connect gain node to destination (speakers)

            this.gainNode.connect(globalAudioContext.destination);

            oscillator.start(0);

            // tone will play for 1.5 seconds 

            oscillator.stop(globalAudioContext.currentTime + 1.5);
        }
    }


}
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) =>
{
    const audio = new Audio();
    let key = e.key;
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    audio.createNotes(key);

})
```

If you're trying to make a keyboard piano, you should have each key bound to a pre-initialized graph node (Gain Node) and reuse them.

And the reason why it starts working again is because it takes time for the garbage collector to kick in.

Comment: Wow - thank you so much. I thought that I was only creating one audioContext in my constructor function, but clearly I was wrong! I've only been researching this web-audio api for a couple of days, so I still have much to learn!